# git:how to push commits to the existing pull request from another person?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Say there's a central repo `A` which my coworkers and I have forked and added an remote as `upstream`. A coworker of mine has sent a pr and I wanted to do something on his commit. So I fetched it directly by `$ git fetch upstream pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME`. I made some changes on it and I want it to be filed up on the existing pr. I added his forked repo as a new remote and tried `git push newRemote BRANCHNAME` but it said:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/emeroad/pinpoint.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

I don't understand what's going on. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Read the part about `hint: 'git pull ...'`, as it is basically telling you what you need to do here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the question seems to be not what to do but why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible his PR branch has changed since the PR was done:

- you fetch from upstream
- he could have added new commits on his PR branch
- you are pushing to newRemote (his repo)

Check first if, by fetching again the PR branch, you see any changes.

The OP adds:

> His pr hasn't changed but the master branch of upstream has been updated a lot so I rebased to the master on the pr branch

Any rebase means the commits are recreated. From there, any push (to any remote) would be a force push.

Comment: His pr hasn't changed but the master branch of upstream has been updated a lot so I rebased to the master on the pr branch.

Comment: @DongBinKim OK. I have edited my answer. Any push after a rebase is a force push.

Comment: So would it be fine if I add `-f` flag?

Comment: @DongBinKim Yes, that will update the PR.

Comment: @DongBinKim Well done. I am glad it worked.